# Accessibility in html: focus and speak?

Tags: ios, webview, accessibility, wai-aria

I work with the following html code in iOS with UIWebView:

```
  <body>
    <p><strong>IMPORTANT:</strong> This is desc text.</p>
...
    </body>
```

I want focus and speak 'IMPORTANT: This is desc text.' while be with accessibility, if I used the following , only focus and speak 'IMPORTANT'

```
    <body>
    <p aria-selected="true" ><strong>IMPORTANT:</strong> This is desc text.</p>
...
    </body>
```

if I use the following, can focus all but NOT speak IMPORTANT

```
    <body>
    <p aria-selected="true" ><strong aria-hidden="true">IMPORTANT:</strong> This is desc text.</p>
...
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `aria-selected` incorrectly. It is supposed to be only used inside a (complex) widget role to indicate which portion of the widget has focus. Examples of correct use are menus or tablists.

If you want to focus a portion of the document to get it to be announced immediately use `tabindex="0"` or `tabindex="-1"` (depending on whether you want the element to be focussed when tabbing through the document) and then `element.focus()` at the appropriate time.

```
<body>
<p tabindex="0" ><strong>IMPORTANT:</strong> This is desc text.</p>
...
<script>
...
// When the element should be focussed
element.focus();
...
</script>
</body>
```

However, you might rather want to use `role="alert"` to get information to be announced automatically without having to set the focus at all.

Comment: I try your solution but failed.

Comment: how did it fail? Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to focus on any of the elements you can use ***tabindex="0"***, tabindex defines the order in which you want your elements to receive focus.

And if you want to make read any of the text you can use ***aria-label*** attribute to achieve it.

For Example: If you want to read "IMPORTANT: This is desc text." just use
**aria-label="IMPORTANT This is desc text."**